# GCM notifications sometimes coming late

Tags: java

I am using GCM server for push notifications, but sometimes the notifications are coming in late. Could anyone please assist me to understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a guarantee notifications arrive on time or arrive at all. Google has to locate the phone and that might take time. Its not a reliable method, but its the best we have currently. If you want something more reliable, you need to use internet/network based communication methods.

Comment: Thanks Mr.breakline.So this delay is from google not code issue.thanks